# What does an Object variable type mean?

Tags: java, types, methods, argument-passing

I am trying to understand the difference between 2 methods that have the same name. This is the code I am trying to understand...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint();
        MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint(10, 30.5);
        System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));
        System.out.println(MyPoint.distance(p1, p2));
    }
}

class MyPoint {
    .....   
}

public double distance(MyPoint secondPoint) {
    return distance(this, secondPoint);
}

public static double distance(MyPoint p1, MyPoint p2) {
    return Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y));
}
```

Could someone please explain the difference between the 2 `distance()` methods. What does the type `MyPoint` actually mean? Why does 1 of the methods have a single `MyPoint` object, whereas the other method has 2 `MyPoint` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyPoint` is the type of the object. In the `distance(MyPoint p1, MyPoint p2)` method, for example, it means that you are passing in 2 objects to this method - the first object is a `MyPoint` object called p1, and the second object is another `MyPoint` object called p2.

The difference between the 2 println statements is that the first one runs the `distance(MyPoint)` method, and the second one runs the `distance(MyPoint, MyPoint)` method. Additionally, the first method runs the `distance()` from the `MyPoint p1` object to the one passed in to the method (`p2`), whereas the second `distance()` method is a static call which calculates the distance between the 2 `MyPoint` objects passed in to the method (`p1` and `p2`).

Comment: Embarrassed to ask but why in the parameter it can contain the classname but not the type like String or int?

Comment: It can contain either. If its something like an int or a boolean, its referring to a primitive type of data, like simple numbers or true/false. If its something like a String, MyPoint, or any other class name, it means its a type of object, which can be more complex than a simple primitive type of data

Comment: I know where I misunderstand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the way you are calculating. First one does it by the instance's state and second one in by 'static' way.

You might want to look at the real usage. If it is like utility, it makes more sense in make it static.

Answer (score 0):

distance is the method that is used to calculate the distance between two points given as input.

The Class MyPoint depicts point in space. now method distance(Mypoint x) in this class gives you the distance of this point from the reference point passed as parameter, while the static method simply returns the distance between two points passed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is about the static methods?

```
p1.distance(p2)
```

this calls a member function of MyPoint, this call is from a particular instance of MyPoint p1
however

```
MyPoint.distance(p1, p2)
```

calls a static method of MyPoint, which doesn't need any instance, but you must add MyPoint. to tell the compiler you are refering to a static method or field.